# PHP Contact Form message length

Tags: php, html, forms

So I have a contact form which is working fine but I need to amend it to remove the message field so that the form is just name, email and submit. But because the php code I am using checks for Message length of 5 this doesn't seem to be working, this is the original php code:

```
<?php


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'email@blahblah.com'; // Your Email
$message_min_length = 5; // Min Message Length


class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin, $message_min_length){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'Contact from Your Website'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['message']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;
        $this->message_min_length = $message_min_length;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check message length
        if(!$this->message || strlen($this->message) < $this->message_min_length)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }
    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email, $message_min_length);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
    <?php
/*
* Subscribe Form Class
*/


header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');

$admin_email = 'email@blahblah.com'; // Your Email



class Contact_Form{
    function __construct($details, $email_admin){

        $this->name = stripslashes($details['name']);
        $this->email = trim($details['email']);
        $this->subject = 'New Subscriber To Your Mailing List'; // Subject 
        $this->message = stripslashes($details['name' + 'email']);

        $this->email_admin = $email_admin;

        $this->response_status = 1;
        $this->response_html = '';
    }


    private function validateEmail(){
        $regex = '/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';

        if($this->email == '') { 
            return false;
        } else {
            $string = preg_replace($regex, '', $this->email);
        }

        return empty($string) ? true : false;
    }


    private function validateFields(){
        // Check name
        if(!$this->name)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter your name</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check email
        if(!$this->email)
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter an e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

        // Check valid email
        if($this->email && !$this->validateEmail())
        {
            $this->response_html .= '<p>Please enter a valid e-mail address</p>';
            $this->response_status = 0;
        }

    }


    private function sendEmail(){
        $mail = mail($this->email_admin, $this->subject, $this->message,
             "From: ".$this->name." <".$this->email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$this->email."\r\n"
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail)
        {
            $this->response_status = 1;
            $this->response_html = '<p>Thank You!</p>';
        }
    }


    function sendRequest(){
        $this->validateFields();
        if($this->response_status)
        {
            $this->sendEmail();
        }

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = $this->response_status;   
        $response['html'] = $this->response_html;

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}


$contact_form = new Contact_Form($_POST, $admin_email);
$contact_form->sendRequest();

?>
```

For some reason this keeps reading the check message length even though its been removed 
please can some one help!

This is the html form btw not that its really necessary, obviously I removed the message field.

```
 <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="_include/php/contact.php" method="post">
      <p class="contact-name">
        <input id="contact_name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
      </p>
      <p class="contact-email">
        <input id="contact_email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
      </p>
      <p class="contact-message">
        <textarea id="contact_message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="contact-submit"> <a id="contact-submit" class="submit" href="#">Send Your Email</a> </p>
      <div id="response"> </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're not using the old original class?

Comment: What is the error returned by PHP ?

Comment: I am using the same original class but its in a differnt html file. There is no error, but when you hit submit the message for Please enter your message. It should have at least '.$this->message_min_length.' characters</p> appears